# Replacement for "prev_ds" and other templated variables in airflow

Tags: airflow

Looking at official documentation [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html), it seems that the `prev_ds` and other variables are being deprecated and we need to replace them with other variables. Is there a variable that provides this directly?

We do get `ds` and `ds_nodash` that we can subtract from, but was wondering if there was another variable that just gives me the previous date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get dag_run with Jinja template and from it to get the prev dag.

for example, for prev_ds you can use :

```
"{{ dag_run.get_previous_dagrun().execution_date | ds }}"
```

for prev_ds_nodash

```
"{{ dag_run.get_previous_dagrun().execution_date | ds_nodash }}"
```